# extracting data from an array of arrays

Tags: objective-c

I have the following code:

```
NSString *movies = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData7 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"movies: %@", movies);
array_webdata = [parsedata objectWithString:movies error:nil];
userMovies = [array_webdata valueForKey:@"movies"];
NSLog(@"userMovies: %@", userMovies);
NSMutableArray *arrayCodes = [userMovies valueForKey:@"rtid"];
NSLog(@"arrayCodes: %@", arrayCodes);
```

In first line I save in movies the following:

movies:

> {"movies":[["rtid","770672122"],["rtid","771268706"],["rtid","771240265"],["rtid","9377"]]}

with: `userMovies = [array_webdata valueForKey:@"movies"];`  I store in userMovies:

```
userMovies: (
        rtid,
        770672122
    ),
        (
        rtid,
        771268706
    ),
        (
        rtid,
        771240265
    ),
        (
        rtid,
        9377
    )
```

From here I want to extract the numbers to create another array like :

> codes: (770672122, 771268706, 771240265, 9377)

But with following line, the execution crashes:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayCodes = [userMovies valueForKey:@"rtid"];
```

The error is EXC_BAD_ACCESS. On Debug Area shows no errors

Do you know what is wrong?
Thanks!

**I have edited the question to make it more understandable**

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS. On Debug Area shows no errors

Comment: What does userMovies contain?

Comment: It sure get crashed as all the key are same :)

Comment: That's an array of arrays and yet you are treating it as dictionary.

Comment: @CBredlow the content of userMovies is in the question. trojanfoe Then how I can extract from there the numbers?

Comment: I meant the dictionary when you run it through the debugger.

Comment: @CBredlow I have edited my question. In this way, maybe you understand what I mean. Sorry but my level of English is very basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

I have deleted my last two lines of code:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayCodes = [userMovies valueForKey:@"rtid"];
NSLog(@"arrayCodes: %@", arrayCodes);
```

and added the following

```
NSMutableArray *moviesCodes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int counter = 0; counter<[userMovies count]; counter++){
   [moviesCodes addObject:[[userMovies objectAtIndex:counter] objectAtIndex:1]];
}
```

With this I have stored all the ids in the array called moviesCodes. The problem was that userMovies is an array of arrays

Comment: Yeah, seems like that's what I wrote above.  You'll noticed I used a "for-each" loop though which just looks alot cleaner...

Answer (score 1):

The code you have is clearly not going to work because you are assigning a number (or int, or some type) to a mutable array.  You can't do that.  You need to ADD them to the array since they will be contained IN THE ARRAY, those numbers ARE NOT arrays...

How are you getting it from JSON?  Your array is probably an array of NSDictionary's so you'll want to do something like:

```
for (NSDictionary *aDictionary in userMovies)
{
    [arrayCodes addObject: [aDictionary valueForKey:@"rtid"]];
}
```

You need to start by finding out what's in your array.  Do:

```
NSLog(@"My array contains %@'s", [[userMovies valueForKey:@"rtid"] class]);
```

From there, if you get NSDictionary use the code above, and if you get an array, you'll have to loop through the array like:

```
for (NSArray *anArray in userMovies)
{
    [arrayCodes addObject: [anArray objectAtIndex:1]];
}
```

Comment: I have a NSMutable array called userMovies and the following line to extract: userMovies = [array_webdata valueForKey:@"movies"]; With this, I obtain the userMovies array of my first message

Comment: I have edited my question. I tried your solution but the result is the same

Comment: I've edited my answer... Put this in and tell me what you get:            NSLog(@"RTID Value is of type: %@", [[userMovies valueForKey:@"rtid"] class]);

Comment: crashes in the NSLog line. The error is: 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x6a7a640> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key rtid.'. I think the issue is in valueForKey:@"rtid"

Comment: And using NSLog(@"My array contains %@'s", [userMovies class]); says: My array contains __NSArrayM's